# string being in previous state even after triggering a new request java

Tags: java, string, spring-boot, get

I am working on a spring boot api where I have used a query string and doing some replace operations on it on every get request but even after I trigger a new request the string is in the same state as that of previous `GET` call and the query gets messed up.

Here's my code:

```
 private static String GET_SETS = "Select * from table #check#";
```

Now I have 1 method in the same repository which gets called on a get request:

```
public PagedList getSets(Map params) {
    if (!StringCheck.isEmpty(flattenMap.get("entity_name"))) {
        GET_SETS = GET_CODE_SETS.replace("#check#", " WHERE e.#entity_name# = ?");
        values.add((String)flattenMap.get("entity_name"));
    } else {
        GET_SETS = GET_SETS.replace("#check# #status_check#", "");
    }
}
```

Now whenever a `GET` request is triggered,some changes are done to `GET_SETS` string according to map values,and again in the next requests the same changes are there.

How to solve this? I want the query string to be whats defined at the start on every request. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is most likely caused by using the default scope, which is singleton, when creating your Spring components.

Spring provides the following scopes for creating beans
([source](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.x/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-scopes)):

> - singleton (default):  Scopes a single bean definition to a single object instance for each Spring IoC container
> - prototype: Scopes a single bean definition to any number of object instances.
> - request: Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of a single HTTP request. That is, each HTTP request has its own instance
>   of a bean created off the back of a single bean definition. Only valid
>   in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.
> - session: Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of an HTTP Session. Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring
>   ApplicationContext.
> - application: Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of a ServletContext. Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring
>   ApplicationContext.
> - websocket:   Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of a WebSocket. Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring
>   ApplicationContext.

If we don't specify any scope explicitly, the default singleton scope is used. This means that the service/component is shared between multiple injections, hence it is reused for multiple `GET` requests.

In order to get rid of this behavior, we might use something like request scope, although in this case we have to take care of thread-safety as well.

Other solution is to not use member variables and try to use local variables for things such as `GET_SETS`.